# Error in Oracle Select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field BillNumber in a table where bill numbers can be repeated, and i want to get the last row of a certain bill, I used this statement which works fine on Sql Server but not on Oracle database:

```
select MB.* 
from SADAD.MAINBILLDETAILS AS MB 
   inner join (select BILLNUMBER, Max(CREATEDON) AS LastDate 
               from SADAD.MAINBILLDETAILS 
               group by BILLNUMBER) As LastBill On MB.BILLNUMBER = LastBill.BILLNUMBER AND MB.CREATEDON = LastBill.LastDate 
where not ISREJECTED Is Null 
  and SubStr(MB.BILLNUMBER,1,3) ='301' 
  and CREATEDON Between To_Date('2016/07/19', 'YYYY/MM/DD') 
  and To_Date('2016/10/19', 'YYYY/MM/DD') 
order by CREATEDON
```

Error message:

> ORA-00933: Command not properly ended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, Oracle does not accept the keyword **AS** for table aliases,  only for column aliases.

```
select * from dual as d;
```

---

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 20
```

---

```
select * from dual d;
```

---

```
DUMMY
-----
X
```

Comment: You mean i have to remove all keywords 'AS' when making alias to tables?

Answer (score 2):

You make a mistake in alias of sub query `As LastBill` - delete the `as`. Correct version should look like

```
Select MB.*  
  From SADAD.MAINBILLDETAILS  MB 
 Inner Join (Select BILLNUMBER, Max(CREATEDON) AS LastDate 
             From SADAD.MAINBILLDETAILS 
            Group By BILLNUMBER) LastBill On MB.BILLNUMBER = LastBill.BILLNUMBER AND MB.CREATEDON = LastBill.LastDate 
Where Not ISREJECTED Is Null 
  And SubStr(MB.BILLNUMBER,1,3) ='301' 
  And CREATEDON Between To_Date('2016/07/19', 'YYYY/MM/DD') And To_Date('2016/10/19', 'YYYY/MM/DD') 
Order By CREATEDON
```

Comment: This still has as 'AS' for the first table

Comment: )) Shame on me. Thank you @Aleksej

Comment: I've added 'AS' and I've got the error message I wrote in the queation